# PHP - $_POST variable is not set after form submitting

Tags: php, html, forms, web-services, post

I know it's a really asked question, and I'm writing this after checking almost every similar question already asked. In every posted question the solution was to add a name attribute to the form, but I already did it before getting the error.

So this is the problem:
I'm trying to implement a basic SOAP web service that by now just prints a sentence using the name passed from the submit form. Here I add both client, server and form codes.
I hope someone can help!

soapserver.php

```
$server = new nusoap_server;

$server->configureWSDL('server','urn:server');

$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:server';

$server->register('register',
                array('username' => 'xsd:string'),  //input parameter
                array('return' => 'xsd:string'),    //output
                'urn:server',                       //namespace
                'urn:server#helloServer',           //SOAP action
                'rpc',
                'encoded',
                'Registrar un usuari');             //description

function register($username) {
    return 'L\'usuari '.$username.' s\'ha registrat correctament!'; 
}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

soapclient.php

```
$wsdl = "http://localhost/soapserver.php?wsdl";

$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl,'wsdl');

$err = $client->getError();

if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2>' . $err;
    exit();
}
if ($_POST) {
    echo $_POST;
}
if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
    echo $_POST["user"];
}
```

soapform.html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form name="reg_form" action="soapclient.php" method="POST">
                    Username: <input type="text" name="user"/>
                    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

What I get when I submit the form is just nothing, as the isset($_POST["user"]) and isset($_POST) return false and therefore nothing happens.

Comment: Is there ANYTHING after you soapclient.php in your URL? For example soapclient.php?id=1.  If there is, then you need a variable in your form to compensate for that dynamic.

Comment: Well, you can't just `echo $_POST`, you will have to use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` as the $_POST is an array. Also, if you remove everything from the soapclient.php-file that involves calling the soapserver, just to see if you get $_POST-variables through? Also, turn on showing of all errors in PHP.

Comment: Why exactly are you using SOAP in 2016? Especially with a freaking webform? It doesn't make any sense. SOAP is for use with processing requests written in XML format, and sending a response in XML format.

Comment: @ElroyJetson Yes there it is, there are the 3 submitted parameters (username, password, submit). Which doesn't make sense since the username field is named 'user' not 'username', might be that the problem, but not sure how to fix it or if I'm missing something.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Just tried it and still the same. var_dump($_POST) returns an empty array. About turning on showing errors... how do I do that? I'm new to PHP.

Comment: @r3wt I know it doesn't make much sense, that is just for testing with PHP and web services, it's the first I'm writing so I don't expect to make it efficient, just to see how php works.

Comment: @SergiMascaró well, you should probably save yourself some time and avoid SOAP. It's only in use in some legacy/enterprise environments (such as many european address/postal code lookup services). gradually, most of these services are being replaced with REST, which is much simpler and efficient to work with, not only for the developer but for the machine that has to do the work. Just start with standard post/get requests, then move on to json when you're ready. From someone who has worked with SOAP, and XML in general, you don't want to have that mental load unless you need it for a job.

Comment: You can add the following to the beginning of the file (any file unless you have a central index-file which loads everything else, then put it there): `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`
However, if you're not seeing anything in the file even with just the post-dump, then there is something else wrong, most likely.

Comment: @SergiMascaró read this page http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Comment: @r3wt It's for a university work, maybe I change to REST so I don't end killing anyone. But forgetting about SOAP, this just still doesn't work, a basic and simple form data gathering, as simple as that, still $_POST is empty and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not set either.

Comment: Solved it, had to replace $_POST by $_REQUEST. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @SergiMascaró you must be using a very old version of PHP, or for some reason super's are disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just post it as an answer so anybody having the same issue can find it easily.

I just solved it myself by changing $_POST by $_REQUEST even I still don't know why the other way wouldn't work...

Edit: after checking deeper into it, I've seen with Chrome that the request sent was a GET request while it should have to be a POST. So finally I've fixed it changing the action from `action="soapclient.php"` to `action="/soapclient.php"` and now it sent a POST and the variable $_POST had the value of the username.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
if ((!is_array($_POST)) || (count($_POST) < 1)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)
}
```

Comment: you can use file_get_contents('php://input') in place of POST

Comment: saved my day :D